# Preloader not closing on Load

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

I have create a website for a client of mine using the Jupiter wordpress theme. I'm experiencing a problem when the page loads for the first time - and only the first time so you will need to clear you cache and history to see this issue.

The site uses a preloader that displays (big white screen with a loading animation) whilst the site loads up all fonts, images, javascript etc.

The problem is that when you visit the site for the first time whatever is used to trigger the preload div to close isn't working. If you refresh the page it does work. I have also set up a local site and a staging site but can't replicate the problem on either. The page is loading behind the preloader - its just not closing.

I have support with this theme but they aren't sure what the issue is and aren't very fast about getting bak to me.

You can view the site at:
www.traintogetherltd.co.uk

Any help would be appreciated. I guess I'm looking for a solution to trigger the close of the preloader div.

I have uninstalled/reinstalled plugins and theme but nothing this hasn't helped.

Please let me know if you require any further information.

Many thanks

Comment: All works fine for me. In Firefox, Safari, Chrome. Also all works fine with private browsing. Refrishng page - same results. Cache clear and other..

Comment: yes it working fine in all browser , in case if you want to hide the preloader you can do this by using css , just add this in you style.css,  .page-preloader {display:none!important}

Comment: Thank you for checking. I still get the loading screen. In the console (Chrome) when the preloader has been cleared I can see "ready for rock" appear. When I visit the site initially and the preloader is still visible this doesn't appear. It seem like this is the trigger to close the preloader